# How to assert that some String contains at least one value from the List <String>?

Tags: java, testing, assertion, assertj

I'm testing some UI functionality with Java and AssertJ.
So when I receive some massive string from UI, I should verify if that String contains at least one predefined value from `List<String>`.
It is easy to do opposite thing - verify if list contains at least once some String value but this is not my case. 
I can't find solution in standard methods.

```java
public static final List<String> OPTIONS = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");

String text = "Just some random text with bar";
```

what I need is smth like this :

```java
Assertions.assertThat(text)
                .as("Should contain at least one value from OPTIONS ")
                .containsAnyOf(OPTIONS)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.matches(s -> OPTIONS.stream().anyMatch(option -> s.contains(option)));
```

Comment: or also `.matches(s -> OPTIONS.stream().anyMatch(s::contains));`

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to use Condition and AssertJ assertions like areAtLeastOne(), areAtLeast(), for instance:

```
assertThat(OPTIONS)
.areAtLeastOne(new Condition<>(text::contains,
                                String.format("Error message '%s'", args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/)

```java
assertThat(text.split(" ")).containsAnyElementsOf(OPTIONS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simplified option using AssertJ:

```
.matches(s-> Stream.of("Foo", "Bar", "Baz").anyMatch(s::contains));
```